# Reduce two variables to a ratio

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, fractions

I was playing around with these two functions :
$$
f_1(x)=\frac{a}{ax+b}
\\f_2(x)=\frac{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a+b}}{ax+b}
$$
and I realized that I can rewrite $f_1(x)$ as
$$
f_1(x)=\frac{c}{cx+1} \quad \text{where }c=\frac{a}{b}
$$
This left me wondering if I could do the same with $f_2(x)$ but I don't know how to approach this kind of problem.

Comment: Are you able to isolate $c$ here
$$
\frac{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a+b}}{ax+b} = \frac{c}{cx+1} ?
$$

Comment: Yes, thanks to [symbolab.com](https://www.symbolab.com/)), I know it yields
$$c=-\frac{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a+b}}{x \sqrt{a}\sqrt{a+b}-ax-b}$$

What I'm looking for however is a function equal to $f_2(x)$ that only uses the ratio $c = \frac{a}{b}$.

Comment: But you don't want $c$ to depend on $x$, right? Do same reasoning with $f_1(x)$, what do you notice?

Comment: Well in the case of $f_1(x)$, I see that $c$ does not depend on $x$. I'm guessing that means I can't replace $a$ and $b$ with $c$ in the case of $f_2(x)$?

Comment: Note that for $f_1$ you just divided numerator and denominator by $b$ to get the expression of the desired form.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a hint

$$ \frac{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a+b}}{ax + b} = \frac{\sqrt{a^2+ab}}{ax + b} $$

as

$$ \sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{b} = \sqrt{a \cdot b}$$

now what would happen if you divide both the numerator and denominator by b?

> $$ \frac{\sqrt{a^2+ab}}{ax + b} = \frac{\frac{\sqrt{a^2+ab}}{\sqrt{b^2}}}{\frac{ax + b}{b}} = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{a^2 + ab}{b^2}}}{\frac{a}{b}x + \frac{b}{b}} = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{a}{b}}}{\frac{a}{b}x + 1} = \frac{\sqrt{c^2 + c}}{cx + 1} $$

Comment: Notice $\sqrt{b^2}=|b|$.

Comment: In addition $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$ is only valid in specific cases.